# update date format in SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to convert date format in SQL
The current format is yyyy/mm/dd-hh:mm:ss:sss and I need to convert it to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss CST
I don't really know SQL but did some research and found that I can use instr to find the string and replace it, however, no matter what I try,there is always something off :(
Could anyone here help me with it? thanks in advance.

By the way, it's in oracle sql developer so syntax are different from previous answer. Thanks again

Comment: Is the date stored in a varchar column or in a datetime column?

Comment: Do you need to convert the time zone too (e.g. adjust the time)? If not, then why are you worried about format? Format is a presentation thing. Store your date/time data using appropriate data types (datetime, smalldatetime) and worry about the string format, CST etc. when you *display* the data.

Answer (score 1):

If your current column is stored as a varchar (which it looks like it is based on your example) you can convert it the following way to a datetime.

```
declare @date varchar(25)
set @date = '2012/02/16-09:40:30:000'

select Convert(datetime, Left(@date, 4) + '-' + 
        substring(@date, 6, 2) + '-' + 
        substring(@date, 9, 2) + ' ' + 
        substring(@date, 12, 8)) As NewDate
```

And the result would be `2012-02-16 09:40:30.000`

There are lots of sites that have details on converting datetime:

1. http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx
2. http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/

If the date is stored as a datetime, then you can get your format by doing:

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 120)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm sorry, but is convert even supported in sql server? it doesn't recognize the command

Comment: yes, CONVERT() is supported on sql-server. what are you using for a query?

Comment: Hey, so I think I was confused and misled the thread by saying it's sql server, but actually i'm working in ORACLE sql developer, sigh...
Would you know how to do it if it's in Oracle? if i just use update command by the string or position of the string, will that be easier?

Comment: I tried this,but it didn't work, it make sense to me though...
SET FIRST= Left(FIRST, 4) + '-' + substring(FIRST, 6, 2) + '-' + substring(FIRST, 9, 2) + ' ' + substring(FIRST, 12, 8)
FROM B

Comment: @user1200687 let me see if I can figure it out for Oracle

Answer (score 1):

thank you so much for your guys help! I got this sorted out by other user's help, the command is,

```
update b
set first= to_char(substr(FIRST,1,4)||'-'||substr(FIRST, 6, 2)||'-'||substr(FIRST, 9, 2)||' '||substr(FIRST, 12, 8))
```

Thanks :)
Mylie

Answer (score 0):

The [CONVERT()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function is normally used for this. The third parameter lets you specify the required date formatting.

If the date is already in a string, then convert it first into a date type and then convert it back to a string in the required format.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

If you're using SQL Server and it's a date field you can do:

```
convert(varchar,getdate(),120)
```

Replacing getdate() with the column name

Answer (score 0):

If the date is stored as a `DATETIME`, then you can convert it to a string in the format you want by doing the following:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),YourColumn,120)
FROM YourTable
```

[CAST AND CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @ds varchar(23)='2012/02/16 12:57:03:002'; --your current format
select convert(varchar(30),cast(@ds as datetime),120)+' CST' --new format you specified
```

Comment: for examle, i'm trying to update column first in table b. Original format is varchar(200)
I did this:
select FIRST from B
declare @ds varchar(23)=FIRST
select convert(varchar(30),cast(@ds as datetime),120)+' CST'
but it didn't work, can someone please correct it? sorry if i made stupid mistake, it's my first time using sql

Comment: Update b set [FIRST]=convert(varchar(200),cast([FIRST] as datetime),120)+' CST';

Comment: The variable @ds was declared in the original example only as an illustration.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the command and show missing expression error. i guess it comes down to how to convert the datatype, so i tried cast only to see if i can convert the datatype, here is what i typied: 
SELECT CAST(FIRST AS DATETIME) FROM B
it shows error Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00902: invalid datatype
00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: ORA-00902 is an Oracle error. Oracle does not support datetime and varchar data types, but timestamp and varchar2 instead. Oracle's convert function has a different syntax too.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. are you able to select cast(First as timestamp(2)) from b ?

Comment: I don't think cast or convert are supported in oracle... sorry, i completely mislead you guys....

Comment: No worries. My Oracle is a little rusty, but I did find a resource, techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/index_alpha.php, which does list cast and convert among the standard functionality in PL SQL

Comment: I think for oracle, it maybe specified in the .sql and .ctl file by declaring timezone for that column when you load the file. I'm not sure, will test it tomorrow and let you know. Thanks for the help again